# Python File Line Viewer

Tags: python, file, user-input

I am super confused could use some help please, thank you. I don't know how to write this code the right way.

Write a program that asks the user for the name of a file. The program should read all of
the file’s data into a list and display the number of lines of data that the file contains, and
then ask the user to enter the number of the line that they want to view. The program
should display the specified line.The program should handle the following exceptions by
displaying an error message:
• IOError exceptions that are raised when the specified filename cannot be found or
opened.
• ValueError exceptions that are raised when a non-integer value is given as a line
number.
• IndexError exceptions that are raised when the line number is outside the range of
the data list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. "I am super confused [and] could use some help" is not an actionable question, and "I don't know how to write this code the right way" is not a specific problem. Note that this is **not a discussion forum**; we can't help you puzzle through an assignment specification, we can only help answer **specific questions** that result from your own attempt to solve the problem by writing code.

Comment: Start by making a checklist of what you can and can't do. For example, can you write code that simply asks the user for a file name? Can you write code that opens a file and reads it into a list? Can you write code that handles an exception?

Comment: You need to make an attempt and then post the code from your attempt with the issues you encountered during your attempt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.